# Automatically create record when another is created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database: `Users`, `Roles` and `Membership`. The `Membership` table assigns users to specific Roles.

How could I automatically create the `Membership` record for anytime a new record is inserted in `Users`.

Example: When a user is created and assigned an ID number (# 562), The database would automatically add them to the `Membership` table with a specific role ID.

How could I do this?

Comment: How do you add the record to the users table? Can you not insert the membership record the same way?

Comment: Users can register for an account manually. I'm using ASP.NET Membership, so I'd prefer to have the functionality in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` on `Users` TABLE, that will INSERT the new Row in the `Membership` table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx

Assuming you have a Default RoleID for your new Membership row, when a new User is inserted in Users table, something like this should work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRI_USERS_INSERT on Users
AFTER INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- If you have a Default RoleID, select that into a variable and use it in the INSERT below.
-- For this example, I am using just the number 1
-- Also assumes that the ID for Memberships table is AUTO GENERATED, so it's not in INSERT list.
INSERT INTO Memberships (UserID, RoleID)
    SELECT ID, 1 FROM INSERTED
GO
```